# How to disallow user to select time form extjs timefield not more than maxDate set in datepicker

Tags: extjs

How to disallow user to select time form extjs timefield not more than maxDate set in datepicker?

```
   Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        title: 'Choose a future date:',
        width: 330,
        bodyPadding: 10,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        items: [{
            xtype: 'datepicker',
            minDate: new Date(),
            maxDate: Ext.Date.add(new Date(), Ext.Date.HOUR, + 14)
        },
        {
            xtype: 'timefield',
            minValue: '12:00 AM',
            maxValue: '11:00 PM',
            increment: 60,
            value: '12:00 AM',
        }]
    });
```

Comment: What is the error/problem with the code you have, what have you tried?

Comment: in my datepicker set maxDate to Ext.Date.add(new Date(), Ext.Date.HOUR, + 14) so time field should not allow to select time more than hours mentioned in maxdate

Comment: You need to put that detail in the question. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).